# VBA code that closes excel after inactivity and can run with other macros

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I am looking for code that will close excel after a specified amount of time that the user has been inactive. I have code online for this problem but it does not run correctly with the other macros in my workbook. I need code that can run with other macros and will close after user inactivity. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please add your code to the question so that SO users can better assist you.

Comment: Please see this FAQ to help you improve your question.
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You wont be able to run a macro to "wait" as VBA is single threaded.  You either run the macro to wait for inactivity or run the other macros. you cannot do both

Answer (score 0):

Call macro for the inactivity counter at the end of each macro. Exit inactivity counter macro using global variable passing 0 at the beginning of each macro. Sample code with keyboard only inactivity control:

```
Public br As Integer
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Byte) As Integer
Sub brea()
  br = 0
  'do stuff here
  Call test
End Sub
Sub test()
  br = 1
  Dim t As Integer
  t = 0
  While t < 15
    t = t + 1
    Sleep (1000)
    For i = 0 To 255
        ret = GetAsyncKeyState(i)
        If ret <> 0 Then t = 0
    Next
    Application.StatusBar = t
    If br = 0 Then GoTo Ends
    DoEvents
  Wend
  Application.Quit
  Ends:
End Sub
```